# Find all chatrooms associated with a current user using Group Chat via Actioncable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

Apologies for the basic question. I managed to follow tutorials and build a Group Chat with Action Cable and learned loads from doing so. However, I'm trying to pull up on a specific html page - all the chatrooms associated with a current user. I tried the following but this only gave me my currently displayed direct_message page. I have listed below all my relevant code.

**show.html.erb (In my chatrooms html folder)**

```
<% @chatroomall.each do |chatroom| %>
<div>
<%= @chatroom.name %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

**Rails Log**

```
 Chatroom Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "chatrooms".* FROM "chatrooms" WHERE "chatrooms"."direct_message" = ? AND "chatrooms"."name" = ? ORDER BY "chatrooms"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["direct_message", true], ["name", "Monica and Rodrigo Williams"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**Chatroom.rb**

```
class Chatroom < ApplicationRecord
has_many :chatroomusers
has_many :users, through: :chatroomusers
has_many :messages

scope :public_channels, ->{where(direct_message: false) }
scope :direct_messages, ->{ where(direct_message: true) }

def self.direct_message_for_users(users)
    user_ids = users.map(&:username).sort
    name = "#{user_ids.join(" and ")}"

    if chatroom = direct_messages.where(name: name).first
        chatroom
    else

        chatroom = new(name: name, direct_message: true)
        chatroom.users = users
        chatroom.save
        chatroom
    end

end
end
```

**chatroomuser.rb**

```
class Chatroomuser < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :chatroom
end
```

**message.rb**

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :chatroom
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook]

cattr_accessor :current_user
has_many :chatroomusers
has_many :chatrooms, through: :chatroomusers
has_many :messages
end
```

**Chatrooms_controller.rb**

```
class ChatroomsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_chatroom, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def index
@chatrooms = Chatroom.public_channels
end
def show
@messages = @chatroom.messages.order(created_at: :desc).limit(100).reverse
end
private
def set_chatroom
  @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:id])
end
def chatroom_params
  params.require(:chatroom).permit(:name)
end
end
```

**Direct Messages Controller**

```
class DirectMessagesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

def show
    users = [current_user, User.find(params[:id])]
    @messageduser = User.find(params[:id])
    @chatroom = Chatroom.direct_message_for_users(users)        
    @chatroomall = Chatroom.all
    @messages = @chatroom.messages.order(created_at: :desc).limit(100).reverse
    @messagelast = @chatroom.messages.last(1)
    render "chatrooms/show"
end
private

def chatroomuserlocator
    @chatroomlocator = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
end
end
```

**ChatroomUsers Controller**

```
class ChatroomUsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :set_chatroom
def create
@chatroomuser = @chatroom.chatroomusers.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
redirect_to @chatroom
end
def destroy
@chatroomuser = @chatroom.chatroomusers.where(user_id: current_user.id).destroy_all
redirect_to chatrooms_path
end
  private

def set_chatroom
  @chatroom = Chatroom.find(params[:chatroom_id])
end
end
```

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "chatrooms", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
t.boolean  "direct_message"
end
create_table "chatroomusers", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "chatroom_id"
t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
t.datetime "last_read_at"
t.index ["chatroom_id"], name: "index_chatroomusers_on_chatroom_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_chatroomusers_on_user_id"
end
create_table "create_messages", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "chatroom_id"
t.text     "body"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.index ["chatroom_id"], name: "index_create_messages_on_chatroom_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_create_messages_on_user_id"
end
```

Comment: What's the schema like for chatroom user? Maybe you didn't name something properly to naming conventions and activerecord? You're using a join table (chatroomusers) so why isn't there a join in the rails generated SQL query? If chatroomusers has a user_id and chat_room_id they may not be named properly as the SQL join isn't being generated.

Comment: @OneNeptune thank you so much for your responding. I've updated the question with my schema and chatroom_users controller. The join is there via chatroom.rb model using  name = "#{user_ids.join(" and ")}" at least I believe so.

Comment: I've provided an answer but if you are still struggling then feel free to open a chat as I think you are struggling with a few basic Rails concepts and I'm happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `class User < ApplicationRecord` you have the following declaration

```
has_many :chatrooms, through: :chatroomusers
```

this allows an instance of the User class to get all chatrooms the user is associated with.

Given that you are asking for

> all the chatrooms associated with a current user

and in your view template you have

```
<% @chatroomall.each do |chatroom| %>
<div>
<%= @chatroom.name %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

You need to fix the @chatroom.name to reference the local chatroom variable setup by `@chatroomall.each do |chatroom|`by changing the code to

```
<%= chatroom.name %>
```

Note that you are now referencing local variable rather than the global @chatroom setup by your controller

You can either setup the controller show action to provide the instance variable `@chatroomall` by amending the show action to look like this

```
def show
    users = [current_user, User.find(params[:id])]
    @messageduser = User.find(params[:id])
    @chatroom = Chatroom.direct_message_for_users(users)        
    #@chatroomall = Chatroom.all Change this to
    @chatroomall = current_user.chatrooms
    @messages = @chatroom.messages.order(created_at: :desc).limit(100).reverse
    @messagelast = @chatroom.messages.last(1)
    render "chatrooms/show"
end
```

Note the change

```
#@chatroomall = Chatroom.all Change this to
@chatroomall = current_user.chatrooms
```

or change your template to loop through current_user.chatrooms

** UPDATE **
This assumes that somewhere you have a current_user. If the name of your currently logged in user instance is not current_user then change current_user to match

Comment: thank you so much for your help on this matter. It worked great, I was hoping that if you have a sec you can help me with this related issue. I tried following your example and applying it to get the last message for each of the chatrooms belonging to the current user. I was able to come far, but my section is stuck in an array. How can i just show the body section , this is the code in my html view - `<%= chatroom.messages.last(1) %>`

Comment: @Omar Please ask this as another question, feel free to come back here and point me to it and I'll gladly take a look

Comment: thank you so much I've just put it into a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096732/find-image-of-messaged-user-associated-with-chatrooms-using-group-chat-via-actio

Comment: if you have a free second and can take a chance to look at this new question that I'm totally stuck on regarding search would be amazing sir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230346/how-to-use-elasticsearch-searchkick-to-run-a-search-bar-on-my-navbar-and-show-re